# Is PHP necessary to use MySQL?

Tags: php, c++, mysql

When I see people using MySQL, it's generally via the PHP bindings. Is it possible to interact with MySQL using C++, or do I need to learn PHP first?

Comment: C++, like most languages, allow MySQL accesses. The reason PHP is mentioned everywhere is 1. PHP is usually used to script web sites 2. PHP is considered easier than, say, C++.

Comment: Imho this question should be reopened now that it's been edited.

Comment: That is not a question but a google request I'd say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use MySQL with many other languages.
You just need a driver, [a list is available here](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's [possible](http://www.nitecon.com/tutorials-articles/develop/cpp/c-mysql-beginner-tutorial/). No, you don't have to learn PHP first.

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning to create websites or web services - PHP. If desktop programs - C++. If you need MySQL just to store and analyze some data (a la MS Access) - neither.

Answer (score 1):

There are MySQL bindings for [many languages](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connectors-apis.html#connectors-apis-summary), including C++.